# Two floating action buttons next to each other

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

The material design documentation has an example of Google Maps showing two floating action buttons next to one another (actually, one above the other).

[image]

How is this done? I have two FAB's in a coordinator layout, but they end up on top of one another, so you only see one button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Use ThemeOverlay to make the toolbar and tablayout text
             white -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:background="#C5C5C5"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_baby"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_name"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:hint="Date of birth"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cake"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/img_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/img_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give the code you already have? That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: post the code you have tested

Comment: I haven't played with `CoordinatorLayout` yet, but is there any reason why you wouldn't wrap your two FABs in a `LinearLayout`, the way you wrapped the other stuff in its own `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @CommonsWare The first time I tried that I couldn't see the FAB's at all. I've since discovered the elevation property and applying that to the layout seems to work. I'm mixing that with PageNotFound's answer to get the right gap between the buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is a combination of layout gravity and anchor gravity together with playing with the margins (of the anchored item) that can make it work, have a look at the xml below which I have used successfully:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />
```

Comment: I'm not able to get any space between the two buttons. They are stuck together

Comment: @JyotmanSingh try setting the bottom margin - e.g. `android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"`

Comment: I was unable to add proper padding between the two fab buttons but I was able to "hack" it a little bit by using: `android:translationY="-16dp"`

Answer (score 24):

Try to use this `app:useCompatPadding="true"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabBottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_search"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomSheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@color/accent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_location_on"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/fabSearch"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"/>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it works perfectly even without Relative layouts and with animations. Thanks Juan

Comment: What are `bottomSheet` and `fabSearch` here?

Comment: @XtremeBiker the post just talk about two fab buttons

Comment: Worked for me. Because I was using a DrawerLayout on my main activity, I had to put the CoordinatorLayout as a child of the DrawerLayout. The floating buttons would be children of the CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my solution, just put an invisible FAB between the two fabs, and works well with CoordinatorLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_invisible"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_follow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_follow"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_invisible"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />
```

[No Snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOD9e.jpg)

[With Snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZieA.jpg)

Comment: Works for me also.. Adding just margins and all doesnot work when setting anchor..

Comment: Works for me as well.  I use a <Space> view to separate the fabs and thus it is no longer a weird solution from my perspective.  Should be the accepted answer since it makes proper use of the anchor concept without tricking the layout using margins.

Comment: Does not work on device orientation change (the second fab vanishes)

Answer (score 11):

I can't believe no one has posted the correct answer.

Wrap the buttons in a `ViewGroup` and apply the [`dodgeInsetEdges`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html#dodgeInsetEdges) layout
parameter so that the buttons move up with the bottom sheet. For the above use
case, we can use a `LinearLayout` with the XML attribute
`app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"`.

Note that we can apply this to *any* view in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ... >

    <!-- We can use any ViewGroup here. LinearLayout is the
         obvious choice for the questioner's use case. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/upperFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/upper_fab_icon" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/lowerFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/lower_fab_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It worked partially. And when I inserted those two lines to encapsulating linear layout it worked perfectly.

`android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: There's a "deprecated" background image in the linked documentation...

Answer (score 6):

This works for me - FABs are embedded in Relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.github.openeet.openeet.SaleDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom" >


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fab_print"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fab_print" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_print"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fab_share"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This solution works (i.e. spacing is preserved) even when the window is resized due to the opening of the input panel. The spacing is lost with other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_scrolling"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/big_activity_fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_scrolling"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_scrolling2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="65dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_scrolling"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

---

this is work for me. the key code is *android:layout_margin="65dp"*

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way (that worked for me!) was to just put the two floating buttons in a vertical linear layout at the bottom/end of its parent.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Just adjust the layout_margin attributes for the floating buttons to get the spacing as you want it.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900363/401025 has a major problem: we are not able to set any margins between the two buttons. They stick together.

It seems that at the current state of the design support library v23.3.0 we are not able to have multiple float actions buttons in a coordinator layout that behave correctly. However in the spec https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions this feature is described so we can expect it in the future.

**As for know I discovered a workaround:**

When you have a look at the google maps android app, you will notice that the first (blue) float action button is floating with the bottom sheet, while the second (my location) button is not. So for the second button create a wrapping relative layout that spans the entire layout. Put it above your bottom sheet layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/secondButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"/>
```

This will exactly mimic the float action buttons of google maps. One drawback with this solution is that you have to set the bottom margin of the wrapper to position the button above the first button. You can do this either in the layout or programmatically:

```
((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) wrapper.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, bottomMargin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two floating action buttons with 100dp space in between them is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_camera"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (at the time of writing this) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900363/4414887 worked only partially as the buttons were sticking together.

I was unable to use any other provided answers as well. So I found a workaround.

**Add a view in between the 2 FABs** like so -

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/view"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar2" />
```

Comment: I like this answer better, which does not require introducing another layer of layout

Answer (score 0):

Three buttons one above other:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_zoom_out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_zoom_out"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_zoom_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|top"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_zoom_in"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_zoom_out"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="start"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_reset_orientation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|top"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_reset_orientation"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_zoom_in"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="start"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another Suggestion**

You can also create either vertical or horizontal **LinearLayout** which may contain several **FloatingActionButton**s and anchor the LinearLayout to a specific target view inside your **CoordinatorLayout**.