# Android How to put a FloatingActionButton in right position?

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I'm trying to put a FloatingActionButton on the map.
I want to put two buttons on the "botton|right" position of the map but it doesn't work well.

[image]

This is what I can see on design and I want to make like this. But, after I upload the code to my phone, I can see those buttons are not staying there.

This is how it works on my phone. (Sorry that the picture is too big..)

[image]

This is my code.. Please take a look at it

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"   
tools:context="com.example.gpgpt.myapplication.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_layout"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="출발지" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/departure"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="도착지"
                    />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/arrival"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:text="Search" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTmap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/current_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please refer to [Multiple floating action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205720/two-floating-action-buttons-next-to-each-other) this link. Hope this help.

Comment: can you post an image of your resulting layout, this code seems fine

Comment: @rawcoder064 Thank you! I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Davi oh of course! I just added an image.

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead of Linear

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gpgpt.myapplication.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="304dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="출발지" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/departure"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="도착지" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/arrival"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="88dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:text="Search" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTmap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/current_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you design any screen have the Nexus 4 phone of the 4.7-inch screen. The design which you see in that screen will not change when you run on bigger phones. And use Constraint Layout instead of Linear or Relative layout because it gives you a very good result on the UI part.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is definitely overcomplicated, but may be you should do this (notice LinearLayout parent of fabs changed to ConstraintLayout):

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTmap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/navigate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="28dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/current_location"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/current_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="28dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work well... The app just set down right after I run it. but Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Pls share code that places map into your layout. May be it will help to better understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

This is about how you display the map, actually your `linearLayoutTmap` exists at the end of the layout, but below that you are creating the map, so the map comes under `linearLayoutTmap` which contains the floating buttons.

what you have to do is that to put `linearLayoutTmap` inside a `RelativeLayout` in which you have to mention that `linearLayoutTmap` exists at the right bottom, in addition you have to change `LinearLayoutTemp` width & height to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`, and finally to put a `fragment` inside the `RelativeLayout` to display the map using it, so it will be all like the following:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTmap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/navigate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/current_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```